# Evaluation SQL in web

Tags: javascript, html, sql, eval

Does anybody know how I can evaluate SQL queries with HTML or JavaScript. I was told that you can evaluate queries in HTML5 but I can't find anything on that. If anyone can point me somewhere that would be great. Thank you

Comment: Web SQL Database, https://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/ does still work in my browser. Although it is deprecated.

Comment: What do you mean by "evaluating SQL queries"?

Comment: im creating a database learning site and i want an interactive tool that my users can like practise quering. so like having a table and have them practising on it. but i dont know how to evaluate the sql statements